# Convert an uploaded from desktop image to black and white in Qt

Tags: image, qt

My program consists of two functions: first a user clicks a button (btn_image) to upload an image from desktop and it displays on the label (lbl_image). Secondly, I push another button (cnv_image) in order to change the colors of that uploaded image to black and white.

I have managed to implement the first function: the image chosen by a user successfully displays. However, I am confused how to convert that image to b&w. I wrote a function that is triggered after clicking the cnv_image button, but the problem is to refer to that uploaded image. So, when I click cnv_image buttom the uploaded image simply disappears.

I tried to use image.load (ui->lbl_image) to refer to the label which contains the image but it shows a mistake.

How can I implement my second function?

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_image_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("Images (*.png *.jpg *jpeg)"));
    if (QString::compare(fileName, QString()) != 0) {
        QImage image;
        bool valid = image.load(fileName);

        if (valid) {
            ui->lbl_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        }
    }


}



void MainWindow::on_cnv_image_clicked()
{
    QImage image;
    image.load(ui->lbl_image);

    QSize sizeImage = image.size();
      int width = sizeImage.width(), height = sizeImage.height();

    QRgb color;

    for (int f1=0; f1<width; f1++) {
            for (int f2=0; f2<height; f2++) {
                int gray = qGray(color);
                image.setPixel(f1, f2, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
            }
        }

    ui->lbl_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 'image.load(ui->lbl_image);' - that should this do? Please read the documenation of [QLabel on how to retireve the current QLabel pixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop). You should also take look at [QImage::convertTo()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#convertTo) instead doing the conversion by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I update your code, I add `QImage          image;` as private member of MainWindow class so In `mainwindow.h` :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void  on_btn_image_clicked();

    void  on_cnv_image_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QImage          image;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**and in `on_cnv_image_clicked` function**

```
void  MainWindow::on_cnv_image_clicked()
{
    QSize  sizeImage = image.size();
    int    width = sizeImage.width(), height = sizeImage.height();
    QRgb   color;
    int    value;

    for (int f1 = 0; f1 < width; f1++)
    {
        for (int f2 = 0; f2 < height; f2++)
        {
            color = image.pixel(f1, f2);
            int  gray = (qRed(color) + qGreen(color) + qBlue(color)) / 3;
            image.setPixel(f1, f2, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
        }
    }

    ui->lbl_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    ui->lbl_image->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

Result :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a good idea to keep a copy of the [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html) in your class when you load it. It helps to avoid extra conversions from [`QPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html) to [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html) in next steps. I'll skip it because it's out of the scope of your question.

You can use [`QImage::convertTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#convertTo) to convert the format of a [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html) in place. It means that, it does not create a new [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html). As per documentation it may **detach** the [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html). You can read more about [**Implicit Sharing**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/implicit-sharing.html) if you are interested.

So, the implementation should be something like:

```
void MainWindow::on_cnv_image_clicked()
{
    QImage image = ui->lbl_image->pixmap().toImage();
    image.convertTo(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    ui->lbl_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

Take a look at the list of [`QImage::Format`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#Format-enum)s to evaluate other grayscale/mono options.